# Angular - directive link isnt called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have wrote a directive which has a link function which isnt beeing called, the templae is injected to the DOM

```
function() {
'use strict';

// Define the directive on the module.
// Inject the dependencies. 
// Point to the directive definition function.
angular.module('app').directive('nvVideo', ['$window', nvVideo]);

function nvVideo ($window) {
    // Usage:
    // 
    // Creates:
    // 
    var directive = {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        alert('ggg');
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div id="slot1">video slot</div>'


    };
    return directive;

}
})();
```

Comment: Your directive looks fine. Can you show how you're referencing it in your view, or possibly create a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <n-video></n-video>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('nVideo', ['$compile', function ($compile) {

    return{
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div id="slot1">video slot</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            alert('ggg');
        }
    }
}]);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/78pC9/)**